# Synchronous vs Asynchronous Clustering

Tags: mariadb, mysql-cluster, galera

I was reading the mariaDD knowledge base on Galera Cluster and i came across this:

The basic difference between synchronous and asynchronous replication is that "synchronous" guarantees that if changes happened on one node of the cluster, they happened on other nodes "synchronously", or at the same time. "Asynchronous" gives no guarantees about the delay between applying changes on "master" node and the propagation of changes to "slave" nodes. The delay can be short or long. This also implies that if master node crashes, some of the latest changes may be lost

With the last sentence, i have always understood that even though the updates on the slave in the asynchronous cluster setup is not performed at the same time, it logs these updates to a bin log file as the updates are being made on the master. So in the case that the master crashes before all the data is passed on to the slave, the updates will still go ahead when the master is restored since the bin log file logged the updates. Can somebody please tell me if my understanding is wrong and clarify on the matter for me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your example of a normal replication pair, the slave would catch up after the master comes back.  Assuming the master does come back, you wouldn't really lose the data but if the master is permanently dead, the data is lost.  The knowledge base article you mention is talking about the replication delay and not the overall integrity of the replication stream.

With normal replication, if the slave io thread (the part that gets the replication events from the master) is able to keep up with the master, then the slave may only lose a couple seconds if the master crashes.  However, if it cannot keep up and is for example 1 hour behind, the slave would lose access to 1 hour of data.  Another way you could lose access to data on the slave is if you have a max relay log size set and that is reached.

Galera makes sure that the write is sent to every node in the cluster before it is actually committed on any of the nodes so once the node that the write is done on commits the write, all of the other nodes will commit the same write.  With galera, all writes basically happen at the same time on every node.  Losing any node at any time during normal operation will not cause any data loss.